# React JavaScript with ES6 compiling issue under browserify and babel

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gulp, browserify, babeljs

I am trying to create a basic React component with the recently introduced ES6 syntax.

My current file schema looks like this:
I have a root feed.jsx file which SHOULD import React and my custom components

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import FeedApp from './components/FeedApp';

var target = document.getElementById('FeedApp');
ReactDOM.render(FeedApp, target);
```

My FeedApp, which imports another component, looks like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import Header from './Header';

class FeedApp extends React.Component{
  constructor(){
    this.state = {
      customHeading: "Hello"
    }
  }
  render() {
    return (
        <div className="clearfix wrapper">
          <Header />
        </div>
    );
  }
}

export default FeedApp;
```

The imported Header component is also a basic one:

```
import React from 'react';

class Header extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return(
      <div className="top-bar">
        <div className="top-logo-wrapper">
          <a href="/" title="Homepage">
            <img src="/imgs/logo-b.png" alt="Logo" />
          </a>
          <a href="/" title="Homepage">
            <h1>Title</h1>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Header;
```

And last but not least my gulpfile content, which should compile everything into one file:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var browserify = require('browserify');
var babelify = require('babelify');
var source = require('vinyl-source-stream');

gulp.task('build', function () {
  browserify({
    entries: 'public/js/build/feed.jsx',
    extensions: ['.jsx'],
    debug: true
  })
  .transform(babelify)
  .bundle()
  .pipe(source('public/js/build/bundle.js'))
  .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});

gulp.task('default', ['build']);
```

Right after running the gulpfile I get the following output:

```
[12:15:49] Working directory changed to /path/folder
[12:15:49] Using gulpfile /path/folder/gulpfile.js
[12:15:49] Starting 'build'...
[12:15:49] Finished 'build' after 22 ms
[12:15:49] Starting 'default'...
[12:15:49] Finished 'default' after 7.46 μs

events.js:141
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^
SyntaxError: 'import' and 'export' may appear only with 'sourceType: module'
```

I have read that this might be a babel issue since it doesn't provide any "addons" automatically any more. If it is so - would anyone be so kind and help me edit my gulpfile.js (or other file) so that I have everything set up to use the glories of ES6 and react ?

Thank you :)

Comment: What version of babelify do you use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or npm install --save-dev babel-preset-es2015 babel-preset-react and;

```js
.transform(babelify, {
  presets:["es2015", "react"]
})
```

Comment: That example was from a gulp config. I am no longer using gulp so don't have the complete example.

Answer (score 1):

First install the presets by running

```
$ npm install --save-dev babel-preset-es2015
```

Now create a `.babelrc' file in your root directory and add the following code:

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015"]
}
```

Now it should load all the es2015 addons, still not working? be sure to check http://babeljs.io/blog/2015/10/31/setting-up-babel-6/

Comment: also needs babel-preset-react